# Oracle query keeps running when the query contains multiple where clauses and aggregate functions

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am running this select query in oracle. It keeps running until I stop it explicitly. This issue is coming because of the last where clause condition with aggregate function highlighted in the image below.

[image]

**Oracle Query:**

```
SELECT "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_KEY",
       "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1_CUSTOMER_KEY",
       "DATE_INVOICE_DATE_KEY_OUTPUT_VALUE",
       "DATE_DELIVERY_DATE_KEY_OUTPUT_VALUE",
       "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING_WWI_INVOICE_ID",
       "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING_QUANTITY",
       "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING_UNIT_PRICE"
FROM
  (SELECT "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."DELIVERY_DATE_KEY" "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING_DELIVERY_DATE_KEY",
          "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."INVOICE_DATE_KEY" "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING_INVOICE_DATE_KEY",
          "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."CUSTOMER_WWI_CUSTOMER_ID" "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING_CUSTOMER_WWI_CUSTOMER_ID",
          "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."CUSTOMERBILLTO_WWI_CUSTOMER_ID" "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING_CUSTOMERBILLTO_WWI_CUSTOMER_ID",
          "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."WWI_INVOICE_ID" "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING_WWI_INVOICE_ID",
          "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."QUANTITY" "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING_QUANTITY",
          "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."UNIT_PRICE" "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING_UNIT_PRICE",
          "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER"."CUSTOMER KEY" "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_KEY",
          "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1"."CUSTOMER KEY" "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1_CUSTOMER_KEY",
          "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."DELIVERY_DATE_KEY" "DATE_DELIVERY_DATE_KEY_INPUT_DATETIME",
          TO_CHAR("FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."DELIVERY_DATE_KEY", 'YYYYMMDD') "DATE_DELIVERY_DATE_KEY_OUTPUT_VALUE",
          "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."INVOICE_DATE_KEY" "DATE_INVOICE_DATE_KEY_INPUT_DATETIME",
          TO_CHAR("FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."INVOICE_DATE_KEY", 'YYYYMMDD') "DATE_INVOICE_DATE_KEY_OUTPUT_VALUE"
   FROM "STG_FACTTABLELOAD_6364_ASTWK_108" "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"
   LEFT OUTER JOIN "WWI_DESTINATION_REGRESSION"."CUSTOMER" "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER" ON ("FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."CUSTOMER_WWI_CUSTOMER_ID" = "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER"."WWI CUSTOMER ID")
   LEFT OUTER JOIN "WWI_DESTINATION_REGRESSION"."CUSTOMER" "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1" ON ("FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."CUSTOMERBILLTO_WWI_CUSTOMER_ID" = "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1"."WWI CUSTOMER ID")
   WHERE "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1"."VALID TO" =
       (SELECT MAX("VALID TO")
        FROM "WWI_DESTINATION_REGRESSION"."CUSTOMER" "MM"
        WHERE "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1"."WWI CUSTOMER ID" = "MM"."WWI CUSTOMER ID"
          AND "MM"."VALID TO" <= "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."INVOICE_DATE_KEY")
     AND "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER"."VALID TO" =
       (SELECT MAX("VALID TO")
        FROM "WWI_DESTINATION_REGRESSION"."CUSTOMER" "MMM"
        WHERE "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER"."WWI CUSTOMER ID" = "MMM"."WWI CUSTOMER ID"
          AND "MMM"."VALID TO" <= "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."INVOICE_DATE_KEY")) ;
```

Can you please help me why this is happening? Is it some sort of Oracle limitation?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the Indexes on the columns you are using in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 3 self-joins on the CUSTOMER table with analytic functions. Analytic functions break your result set into different windows, and can pull the maximum from each window. Conceptually, this approach is more complicated than a join and a MAX function, but it can significantly improve performance by removing joins.

I don't completely understand your data model, but I think something like this could work:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ...
        MAX
        (
            CASE
                WHEN "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1"."VALID TO" <= "FACTTABLELOAD_STAGING"."INVOICE_DATE_KEY"
                THEN "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1"."VALID TO"
                ELSE NULL
            END
        )
        OVER (PARTITION BY "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1"."WWI CUSTOMER ID") MAX_VALID_TO
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
)
WHERE "DIMLOOKUP_CUSTOMER1"."VALID TO" = MAX_VALID_TO;
```

But this answer is only a guess. If you're still having problems, I suggest you run the query, find the SQL_ID by querying GV$SQL, and then plug the SQL_ID into `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('SQL_ID') from dual;` That report will tell you exactly which operation of the query is slow, and provides helpful information to infer why the plan was chosen.